# Python Regex separate by words and upper case letters, but exclude numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to analyze some CV data and need to tokenize different sections.
When I get the data in (through beautiful soup) it comes out like this:

```
['Middlesex UniversityMA HRMMA HRM2012  –  2014', 'Ryerson UniversityBachelor of CommerceBachelor of Commerce1999  –  2003']


['Program Manager, Global Career DevelopmentHult International Business SchoolAugust 2014  –  January 2017 (2 years 6 months)', 'Director, Career ServicesHult International Business SchoolMarch 2012  –  August 2014 (2 years 6 months)', "Training & Development ManagerWalmartOctober 2006  –  February 2011 (4 years 5 months)• Built management's Leadership and Operations capability through the Retail Academy and field training.", 'Co-Owner/DirectorThai DelightFebruary 2003  –  July 2007 (4 years 6 months)• Developed and executed business strategy, marketing and sales initiatives • Managed all financial statements and reporting • Recruited and trained staff on food safety and customer service', 'Assistant Store ManagerWalmartJune 2003  –  October 2006 (3 years 5 months)• Drove profitable sales in a high volume store through the management of people, operations and merchandise.']
```

So, I'm trying to separate it with regular expressions and this is what I've got so far, and where I'm truly stuck:

```
import re
string = ''.join(schools)
split = re.findall('[A-Z]+[^A-Z]+', string)
split_string = ''.join(split)
print(split)
```

which gives me this:

```
['Middlesex ', 'University', 'MA ', 'HRMMA ', 'HRM2012  –  2014',
'Ryerson ', 'University', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce1999  –  2003']
```

I'm trying to get to either this:

```
['Middlesex ', 'University', 'MA ', 'HRMMA ', 'HRM', '2012', '2014', 'Ryerson ', 'University', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce', '1999', '2003']
```

or this output:

```
['Middlesex ', 'University', 'MA ', 'HRMMA ', 'HRM', 'Ryerson ', 'University', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce', 'Bachelor of ', 'Commerce']
```

Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `HRMMA` into `HRM`, `MA`. How?

Comment: I guess that's wishful thinking, but the important parts would be separating the years out of there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`re.findall()`** solution with specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = "Middlesex UniversityMA HRMMA HRM2012  –  2014', 'Ryerson UniversityBachelor of CommerceBachelor of Commerce1999  –  2003"

result = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z][a-z]+(?: of)?|[0-9]+)', s)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['Middlesex', 'University', 'MA', 'HRMMA', 'HRM', '2012', '2014', 'Ryerson', 'University', 'Bachelor of', 'Commerce', 'Bachelor of', 'Commerce', '1999', '2003']
```

---

- `(...|...|...)` - regex alternation group
- `[A-Z]{2,}` - matches between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible a character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- `[A-Z][a-z]+(?: of)?` - matches a single character in the range from A to Z followed by one or more characters in the range between a to z and optional preposition `of`
- `[0-9]+` - matches one or more digits

Comment: Thank you, that looks great. I will test when I get home. Appreciate it!